# Mapping user record with FB details

Tags: facebook, web-applications, facebook-login

I am not sure if this makes sense to all the techies. Here is my requirement and here is what I have done

I have integrated FB login using the methods mentioned at the elow link.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/getting-started-web/

I want to store some unique token for a user and map it with the user record in my DB. I did some googling but I am not successful. I am sure many websites do this. Please point me to some material so that I can achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just use the user id you get from Facebook.

Comment: how do I get the user Id from FB?

Comment: The example on the page you linked already shows how to make an API request for `/me` - log the whole request object to console if you don’t know what it actually contains.